# Optimizing by translation to map one x,y set of points onto another

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, coordinates, least-squares

I have a list of x,y ideal points, and a second list of x,y measured points. The latter has some offset and some noise.

I am trying to "fit" the latter to the former. So, extract the x,y offset of the latter relative to the former.

I'm following some examples of `scipy.optimize.leastsq`, but having trouble getting it working. Here is my code:

```
import random
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
# Generate fake data. Goal: Get back dx=0.1, dy=0.2 at the end of this exercise
dx = 0.1
dy = 0.2
# "Actual" (ideal) data.
xa = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1])
ya = np.array([0,1,2,0,1,2])
# "Measured" (non-ideal) data. Add the offset and some randomness.
xm = map(lambda x: x + dx + random.uniform(0,0.01), xa)
ym = map(lambda y: y + dy + random.uniform(0,0.01), ya)
# Plot each
plt.figure()
plt.plot(xa, ya, 'b.', xm, ym, 'r.')

# The error function.
# 
# Args:
#   translations: A list of xy tuples, each xy tuple holding the xy offset
#   between 'coords' and the ideal positions.
#   coords: A list of xy tuples, each xy tuple holding the measured (non-ideal)
#   coordinates.
def errfunc(translations, coords):
  sum = 0
  for t, xy in zip(translations, coords):
    dx = t[0] + xy[0]
    dy = t[1] + xy[1]
    sum += np.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
  return sum

translations, coords = [], []
for xxa, yya, xxm, yym in zip(xa, ya, xm, ym):
  t = (xxm-xxa, yym-yya)
  c = (xxm, yym)
  translations.append(t)
  coords.append(c)

translation_guess = [0.05, 0.1]
out = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, translation_guess, args=(translations, coords), full_output=1)

print out
```

I get the error:

> errfunc() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)"

I'm not sure why it says 3 arguments as I only gave it two. Can anyone help?

====

ANSWER:

I was thinking about this wrong. All I have to do is to take the average of the dx and dy's -- that gives the correct result.

```
n = xa.shape[0]
dx = -np.sum(xa - xm) / n
dy = -np.sum(ya - ym) / n
print dx, dy
```

Answer (score 0):

The scipy.optimize.leastsq assumes that the function you are using already has one input, x0, the initial guess. Any other **additional** inputs are then listed in args.

So you are sending three arguments: translation_guess, transactions, and coords.

Note that [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) it specifies that args are "**extra** arguments."

---

Okay, I think I understand now. You have the actual locations and the measured locations and you want to figure out the constant offset, but there is noise on each pair. Correct me if I'm wrong:

xy = tuple with coordinates of measured point

t = tuple with measured offset (constant + noise)

The actual coordinates of a point are (xy - t) then?

If so, then we think it should be measured at (xy - t + guess).

If so, then our error is (xy - t + guess - xy) = (guess - t)

Where it is measured doesn't even matter! We just want to find the guess that is closest to all of the measured translations:

```
def errfunc(guess, translations):
  errx = 0
  erry = 0
  for t in translations:  
    errx += guess[0] - t[0]
    erry += guess[1] - t[1]
  return errx,erry
```

What do you think? Does that make sense or did I miss something?

Comment: Argh, Python I curse thee. Well, changing it to def errfunc(translation_guess, translations, coords): ... doesn't work -- nor do I see a way to actually use the translation_guess inside of errfunc. Any pointers? Have a working code sample?

Comment: I don't have any working code using this, but I'm happy to try to help. I don't think I quite understand what your function is trying to do. On top you say you are looking for the offset, but you describe 'translations' as being the offset. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sure. Just plot it with the "plt.plot" lines included in the code. You will see blue dots and red dots. The blue dots are exact, the red dots have translation and noise. (The translation is common to all red dots -- in this case dx=0.1, dy=0.2. The noise is specific to each red dot.) In the end I'm trying to get back the dx=0.1, dy=0.2 that I artificially put into the data at the beginning. Does that make sense? So, I can know how far offset the red dots are relative to the blue dots.

Comment: Thanks Noam. Almost -- ideally we have two sets of points: (xa,ya) and (xm,ym). We do some magic and it spits out dx=0.1-ish and dy=0.2-ish. So, it does matter where it is measured. Anyway, in case I'm wrong in my thinking I just pasted your errfunc into my code, but it gives the cryptic error: Improper input: N=2 must not exceed M=1. I'm still playing with it, but that is the current status. I feel like it is close though..

Comment: Apparently, the number of inputs in the error function can't be larger than the number of outputs. I don't really understand this, but I did a naive fix above. Also, take out the "full_output = 1". After that it should work, although it doesn't work very well... Maybe try playing around with the error function more, or the initial guesses.

Comment: Oh, I just realized - much simpler approach is just to average dx and dy for each point. That gives the desired result. I'll update the question. Thanks anyway for your help.